# Teaching/learning games for predicate calculus?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, education, card-games

I have fond memories of the teaching game WFF n' Proof, played with dice, which teaches rapid, fluent, and correct use of propositional calculus. I think this game would have gained substantial popularity and would still be widely used were it not for its rule book, written in a style so dense and impenetrable as to be nearly unreadable. The game itself did not suffer from these defects, and was easy to learn (from another person who knew how to play) and fun.

Is anyone aware of a similarly multi-player game intended to develop fluency with the predicate calculus? I'd also like to know if anyone knows of a multi-player game intended to develop fluency with valid statistical reasoning about causation, which I would regard as a natural extension of the predicate calculus. Ideally something that could be used by a class at the high school or undergraduate level.

I would also be interested in single-player computer games intended for this purpose, but only if they are sufficiently well designed that one could imagine someone playing them for fun.